# I need to change the css propety of nth div which is nested inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to row in a matrix of 3x3 and after each wrapper div box i need to show a vertical line.  If i put my code in a repeater control of loop to generate this from code then this creates another issue it adds vertical line after every box.

I was trying to hide 3rd, 6th, 9th div with class name `horizontal-line` so that vertical line wont appear.

I am not sure how i can change below script to change the nth elements inside

`Content-area` div or class

`$('.content-area .horizontal-line:nth-child(6n+1)').css('display', 'none');`

I am looking for jquery Solution(Update)
Example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkbxR/2/)

```
<div id="content-area">
    <div class="article-wrapper">
        <div id="article">
            <div id="title"></div>
           <div id="details"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal-line"></div>  

    <div class="article-wrapper">
        <div id="article">
            <div id="title"></div>
           <div id="details"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal-line"></div>  

    <div class="article-wrapper">
        <div id="article">
            <div id="title"></div>
           <div id="details"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal-line"></div>  

        <div class="article-wrapper">
        <div id="article">
            <div id="title"></div>
           <div id="details"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal-line"></div>  

    <div class="article-wrapper">
        <div id="article">
            <div id="title"></div>
           <div id="details"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontal-line"></div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Well your selector should start with `#content-area` because it's an id, not a class. And if you're trying to select every third `.horizontal-line` why are you using `nth-child(6n+1)`? Note also, unrelated to your problem (probably), your html is invalid because you repeat the same ids all over the place. `id` should be unique, so you should be using classes instead.

Comment: IDs should be unique. You should use class names instead.

Comment: This is just for example in this case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/cjtgL)

```
.content-area .horizontal-line:nth-child(3n){
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: THis is a css property i am not sure if this is supported by IE 8 or below

Comment: It's not. If you really need IE 8 support, use the same selector with jQuery

Comment: I am actually looking for jquery solution.. my mistake didn't mention in question clearly

Comment: [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/LqDZV/) should work in IE8 and lower. Don't have this browser to test it though

Answer (score 2):

content-area isn't a class.

Use `#content-area`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#content-area .horizontal-line:nth-child(3n)')
```

is the way to get there